# How can I get a file or directory name from a file open dialog in PyQt4?

Tags: pyqt4, gis

I am writing a PyQt4 application and one of the file types I wish to open is an Esri Grid format which, rather unusually, is a directory. I also wish to open other GIS filetypes that are just files (e.g. geotiffs). I can open these filetypes OK with the GDAL library by passing either a file or directory name and GDAL figures it out.

The problem I have is making the GUI. I want to open a file open dialog and get **either** a file name, or directory name. The problem is that the file dialog won't let me choose a directory - only files. I need the dialog to return a path to either. I've tried it on Mac and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I know PySide has a method called getExistingDirectory
http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QFileDialog.html

PyQt is basically the same, so it should have a similar method. http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qfiledialog.html It is in the static methods section.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've cracked it. This snippet tests the functionality I need:

```
dlg=QtGui.QFileDialog()
dlg.setFileMode(QtGui.QFileDialog.AnyFile);
e=dlg.exec_()
print dlg.selectedFiles()[0]
```

The solution was to set the file mode to 'AnyFile'. This allows the file dialog to return both directory and file names.